# shell must parse ls -Al output and get last field (file or directory name) ANY SOLUTION

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I must parse `ls -Al output` and get file or directory name

`ls -Al` output :

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 s162103  studs         12 march 28 2012 personal domain
drwxr-xr-x   2 s162103  studs          3 march 28 22:32 public_html
drwxr-xr-x   7 s162103  studs          8 march 28 13:59 WebApplication1
```

I should use only `ls -Al | <something>`

for example:

```
ls -Al | awk '{print $8}'
```

but this doesn't work because `$8` is not name if there's spaces in directory name,it is a part of name. maybe there's some utilities that cut last name or delete anything before? I need to find any solution. Please, help!

EDITED: I know what parse ls -Al is bad idea but I should exactly parse it with construction above! No way to use some thing like this

```
for f in *; do
    somecommand "$f"
done
```

Comment: What about just `ls -1A`? instead of "l" (L), a "1" (one)

Comment: @fedorqui Nice going you should make that an answer.  Especially since you shouldn't parse `ls` output.

Comment: Well, I followed your suggestion and posted the comment as an answer, @squiguy!

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: We prefer that you **don't** cross-post questions on two or more sites: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70630/must-parse-ls-al-output-and-get-file-or-directory-name - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this`ls -Al |awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8="";print $0}'` 
I know it's a cheap trick but since you don't want to use anything other than `ls -Al` I cant think anything better...

Comment: I feed dirty suggesting this, but add `-v OFS=''` to the awk command to get rid of the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Don't parse `ls -Al`, if all you need is the file name.

You can put all file names in an array:

```
files=( * )
```

or you can iterate over the files directly:

```
for f in *; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

If there is something specific from `ls` that you need, update your question to specify what you need.

Comment: my post was edited. I should use exactly ls -Al because i need additional information.

Comment: But *what* additional information? There are [very good reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to not parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: @AlexZern: You'd be far better off using `files=(*)` to get the filenames, and then `ls -l "${files[num]}"` (or maybe `stat`) to get the additional info you need for each file.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @[squiguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114966/squiguy) request on comments, I post my comment as an answer:

What about just this?

```
  ls -1A
```

instead of `l` (L, the letter), a `1` (one, the number). It will only list the names of the files.

Comment: my post was edited. I should use exactly ls -Al because i need additional information.

Comment: @AlexZern What do you mean you need additional information if you are just printing the file names originally?

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that `find` can do what you're looking for:

Everything in this directory, equivalent to `ls`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1
```

Recursively, similar to `ls -R`:

```
find .
```

Only directories in a given directory :

```
find /path/to/some/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

`md5sum` every regular file :

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Comment: my post was edited. I should use exactly ls -Al because i need additional information.

Comment: @AlexZern, the `-printf` option for `find` allows you to get additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Hope awk works for you:

```
ls -Al | awk 'NR>1{for(i=9;i<NF;i++)printf $i" ";print $i}'
```

In case you're interested in sed:

```
ls -Al | sed '1d;s/^\([^ ]* *\)\{8\}//'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling quite a while trying to find a robust solution to parse output of `ls -l`, because when you use sftp client you can't use `find` and other commands to get detailed filelists with info, and format of ls -l outputs is quite misaligned when they have for example very-long file-owner's names, or file-size is over 9 chars long..

I finally came up with following solution, based on `BASH's regex`, which can deal with filenames containing whitespaces or multiple whitespaces:

```
#internal PATTERN for proper parsing ls -L lists, including filenames with spaces
c='([[:graph:]]+)[[:blank:]]+'                # a normal solid column = "[data]+[delimeters]+"
f='(.+)[\x0D]?'                               # filename - any chars till EOL
declare -r _LL_PATTERN="$c$c$c$c$c$c$c$c$f"   # final pattern, would look overcomplicated if defined directly

ll_extract_ftype()  { local data; while read -r -t 9 data; do [[ "$data" =~ ^${_LL_PATTERN}$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]:0:1}"; done; true; }
ll_extract_fname()  { local data; while read -r -t 9 data; do [[ "$data" =~ ^${_LL_PATTERN}$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[9]}";     done; true; }
ll_extract_fowner() { local data; while read -r -t 9 data; do [[ "$data" =~ ^${_LL_PATTERN}$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}";     done; true; }
ll_extract_fgroup() { local data; while read -r -t 9 data; do [[ "$data" =~ ^${_LL_PATTERN}$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}";     done; true; }
ll_extract_fsize()  { local data; while read -r -t 9 data; do [[ "$data" =~ ^${_LL_PATTERN}$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[5]}";     done; true; }
```

basically here:

- the solution uses regex-pattern to parse `ls -l` output by columns,
- where 1st 8 columns are solid some_data/space_delimeter,
- and 9th column - the rest till end of line.
- (have even opitonal \x0D char which is injected by `expect` wrapper around an`sftp` command). then required field is taken from BASH_REMATCH[] array.
- then I've wrapped it into a functions, which processes stdin as input values using `read`, to be able using it in standard linux pipes.
- `-t 9` is just to put timeout to `read`, so if function called directly with empty `stdin`, script won't froze waiting for user's input from console. (Be careful not to put some too short value, because sftp can sometime's be slow on its own and reach this timeout!)

Usage example:

```
$ touch 'some    ugly file name.txt'
$ ls -nl
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 12202 12202 0 Aug 23 11:49 some    ugly file name.txt

$ ls -nl | ll_extract_fname
some    ugly file name.txt

$ ls -nl | ll_extract_fsize
0

$ filename=$(ls -nl | ll_extract_fname)
$ echo "[$filename]"
[some    ugly file name.txt]
```

this solution would not probably work in unix/posix, but imhp: good good enough for  modern linux environments.

I will be glad to hear some other solutions to extract details of files from sftp (type,size,date,fname), which will be robust for dealing with whitespaces in filenames..