# awk or cut field with filename that has space

Tags: awk, cut

From below

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Aug 26 15:20 /home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext
```

I want to extract last column. Expected output:
    /home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext

What I tried with cut:

```
ls -lh  /home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext | cut -d ' ' -f9
```

output:

```
/home/user/public_html/this\
```

What I tried with awk:
    ls -lh /home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext | awk '{print $9}'

output:

```
/home/user/public_html/this\
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)! What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [`Do not parse ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead, just say `ls -h`, without the `l`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721925/shell-must-parse-ls-al-output-and-get-last-field-file-or-directory-name-any-s

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for showing it, I didnt see it before though I first searched for similar post. However ls -Al |awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8="";print $0}' worked to extract last field. it didnt worked if I want to get another field with last field. For example if I want to extract column 5 and 9, what should I be doing?

Comment: @fedorqui I am trying to find the file with certain extension with size.

Comment: then `find` with [`size`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10079804/1983854) and `-name '*.your_extension` may be the solution.

Comment: well I found, find command is much slower than ls command.

Comment: @Err0rr, If you are still interested in parsing the output of `ls` command, then you can try `cut -d ' ' -f 9-`, which means **from 9th field to last**

Comment: @Jdamian Thanks for your suggestion. However it gives me error but I figure it out and what works was `cut -d ' ' -f9-`

Comment: @Err0rr, yes, you are right. There should not be that typo (a blank character between `f` and `9`), but I cannot correct it anymore :(

Comment: @Err0rr, can you clarify what your underlying goal is here? This Q appears to be an example of *two* pitfalls - you're [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)!  Once you find "the file with certain extension with size", what are you planning to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`

```
$ echo "-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Aug 26 15:20 /home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext" | 
  awk -F'[^\\\\] ' '{print $NF}'

/home/user/public_html/this\ space.ext
```

define delimiter as space after a non-backslash char.